# Android Studio ERROR com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

Tags: android

I have Problem for android studio.It not run after i install and have error that "A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade". I try uninstall and reinstall Android studio again but It not work. How I solve it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61271201/206877

Answer (score 0):

Update Gradle, you can do this by updating Android Studio. The current alpha/beta version of the Gradle plugin (version 3.6) also seems to fix this error, so you can install that directly

Comment: Thank  I will try it.