# How to fix this error "A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade"

Tags: android, android-studio

I can't run my app on **AVD**. I get this error.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

My `build.gradle`

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}[E][1]}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'}
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57606462/a-failure-occurred-while-executing-com-android-build-gradle-internal-tasks

Comment: @sanaebadi I fixed 'org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m' in gradle.properties but it's can't work. Still error at same. :(

Comment: send build.gradle for project and gradle-wrapper

Comment: @sanaebadi My build.gradle for project and gradle-wrapper are on my comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57606462/a-failure-occurred-while-executing-com-android-build-gradle-internal-tasks)

Comment: Recommend updating your gradle and gradle plugin as well as your compileSdkVersion (current is 31) and then bump build tools version to match that (should be 30.0.3 to match compileSdk 31).
If you get a "corrupted build tools" error asking you to reinstall the tools ( i did when I first upgraded our project) please see the solution to the below question to fix the issue, you will need to change some file types under the Gralde files
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68387270/android-studio-error-installed-build-tools-revision-31-0-0-is-corrupted

Answer (score 34):

Finally I fixed it.

- Change `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m`
  to `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en`
- Change `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'`
  to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'`

---

[Android Studio - How to fix Internal error when trying to read zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54340943/android-studio-how-to-fix-internal-error-when-trying-to-read-zip-file)

Comment: Thank you man, `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en` worked for me

Comment: I change for my part `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'` to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'`

Answer (score 11):

Simply degrade the version from

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
```

then no need to change anything,

You can try `Invalidate Caches/Restart` if not working.

Comment: Had to downgrade from Gradle version 4.0.0 to 3.4.2 while building with Ionic. Do you by any chance know why this solution works?

Comment: Downgrading from 4.0.1 to 3.4.2  was the only solution that worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This worked:

```
gradle.properties.org.gradle.jvmargs=-xmx4608m
```

Comment: Earlier, invalidate cache and restart worked for me but the problem surfaced again. Then gradle.properties.org.gradle.jvmargs=-xmx4608m worked.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have enough RAM for gradle process by updating **org.gradle.jvmargs** in your **gradle.properties**.

Make sure your Gradle version and gradle plugin are compatible; refer to this table: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle (i suggest plugin 3.5.3 with gradle 5.4.1 as of this writing!)

And what might be happening to some without knowing it, is not using **JDK 8**! I tried with JDK 11 and saw many different R8 and dexing errors! Also looks like this whole setup does not work with **Eclipse OpenJ9 JDK** distribution! so make sure you are using standard OpenJDK of your OS (mine would be default OpenJDK-8 from Debian)

Comment: I modified my `gradle.properties` file with the following line to solve OutOfMemroyError exception while running an Android build. My understanding is that this is double the default memory settings, and that increasing the Xmx value will give better results vs the XX:MaxPermSize parameter. If you need more, just increase the Xmx parameter. `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in my flutter project and it happened suddenly when trying to build/debug. Nothing worked not even "File > Invalidate Caches/Restart..." Finally I did a "flutter clean" and "flutter packages get" and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

It worked.Use these commands on VSCode.

1. flutter clean
2. flutter pub cache repair

Answer (score 2):

Run Flutter Clean, then restart your machine.

That did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are scared of degrading gradle or so, recommend doing it because that resolved the issue for me.
Dowgraded from:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.3'
```

to:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

This error can also be arise due any vector asset.
I resolve by removing that vector asset file.
Please check if you recently made any change to your vector asset file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Android Studio 4.0.0 and everything is fine until suddenly I got this error when clean and rebuild project. I don't know why. I tried many solution suggested but no luck. Finally I try to uninstall Android Studio 4.0.1 and this error is GONE and enable to run in emulator like before

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue, proposed solutions did't work for me.
In my case problem was caused by signing config: I did set `storePassword` field, but didn't set `keyPassword` field in my `signingConfigs` section (passwords were same).
So if you have your signing config in app's `build.gradle` file, try to set `Key Password` field in `File -> Project Structure -> Modules` dialogue or by adding `keyPassword` field in your `signingConfigs` section in `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('C:\\PathToKey\\key.jks')
            storePassword 'myPassword'
            keyAlias 'myAlias'
            keyPassword 'myPassword'
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: For some reason, the way I had it set up to pull the keyPassword from a file stopped working. I'd have NEVER thought to investigate that based on this extremely weird error, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

In my case problem arose due to gradle version upgradation from **6.2 all to 6.6 all** in gradle wrapper. So i wiped data of avd and restarted it and then deleted .**gradle folder in android/.gradle** and then run y**arn start --reset-cache** and **yarn android**. Then it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Adding this line to gradle.properties.

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
```

Comment: Can you give an explanation for why this worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. This solved mine.

1. Change `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'` to `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'`
2. `File` -->> `Invalid caches/Restart`
3. `pubspec.yaml` -->> `pub upgrade`
4. Change dependencies version to latest
5. `Pub get`
6. `flutter run`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I upgrade the compiled SDK version and IT worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your APK is locked by external tool (or even IDE)

```
(...)\app\release\app-release.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was mentioned `android:src = "@drawable/screen"` in launch_background.xml file.

but, could not added image in drawable folder. Putting image screen.jpg in drawable folder fixed my issue.

[image]

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction, I had typo in my launch_screen.xml, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For FLutter, make sure you added android/key.properties

```
storeFile=/Users/umerwaqas/Downloads/keystore/THREADS AI.jks
storePassword=123456
keyAlias=userapp
keyPassword=123456
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In my case I solved the problem

1. uninstalling my antivirus which was fishy (downloaded from chrome).

"ionic cordova build android" command started working again

Answer (score -2):

well the thing i do was simply restarting my computer. It works for a lot of these kind of rubbish errors android studio raises.

Answer (score -2):

player -
publishing setting-
build under -
custom main manifest deselect
build again

Answer (score -3):

My build.gradle (Project)

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My gradle-wrapper

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```